# Special Gridline Style for Only One Column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, gridlines

How would I set a custom grid line style on just one column of a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx)? In particular, I'd like one column to have a double line as its left border.

Example:

```
| Col1 | Col2 || Col3 (w/ Double Left Border) |
```

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where you want this double line. The vertical GridLines is drawn in `OnRender` for `DataGridCell` and the horizontal GridLines is drawn in `OnRender` for `DataGridCellsPresenter`. The border for the `DataGridColumnHeader` is more complicated however. It's a Rectangle that's drawn in the `RenderTheme` method in `DataGridHeaderBorder` and I don't think that there is a direct way to change its width without re-templating the entire `DataGridColumnHeader`. Also, the border thickness for the Headers are twice as thick as the Cells in the `DataGrid` to begin with (1px vs 2px), because the Headers draw their Separators on both sides.

So, to get double line thickness which just affects the Cells you can add a special `DataGridCell` style where you want this to apply. All this cellstyle does is to draw a 1px border to the left in the same colour as the GridLines. It'll look something like this

[image]

```
<DataGrid ...
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Black">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DoubleLeftBorderCell" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=HorizontalGridLinesBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Double left Border"
                            CellStyle="{StaticResource DoubleLeftBorderCell}"
                            Binding="{Binding TextProperty}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

There is no mouseover effect or anything on the cells to worry about. If you do something similar for a `DataGridColumnHeader` however, you'll lose the sorting arrows, mouseover effect, mousedown effect etc. so a you'll have to create an entire template for it

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Header Name">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1 0 0 0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 0 0 0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HorizontalGridLinesBrush}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

This is based on Meleak's answer but with the addition of margin (to create the double-line effect) and using a RelativeSource for the border brush, removing the need for the DataGrid to have a x:Name.