# Remove left border grid line for WPF DataGrid header columns to match data grid lines

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

The border styles for header cells and data cells in a WPF 4.0 DataGrid are inconsistent.. Header cells have a border that includes a left vertical border line and a right vertical border line around the header text. Data grid text column data lines are styled such that only the right side has a vertical border line. The following sample image illustrates this (note that the grid line color has been changed to #D0D0D0):

[image]

Here is the same image zoomed in to show the inconsistency:

[image]

How do you change the grid headers (perhaps via a templates or styles) to remove the left border, so that the header vertical border lines line up with the data border lines?

Comment: An easier solution is to "double the thickness" for the `DataGridCell` s by drawing a separator on both sides. Maybe this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737518/special-gridline-style-for-only-one-column. Otherwise, you'll basically have to re-create the entire template for `DataGridColumnHeader`

Comment: Double thickness borders just look wrong to me, since they are a waste of horizontal space. I would like to make all of my grid lines, header and data the same width, one unit.

Comment: I totally agree and I've tried that myself a couple of times. The problem is that most of the parts for `DataGridColumnHeader` are drawn in code behind and as soon as you change anything, e.g set the Background to Green, then you lose the entire style.

Comment: On a side note, the RowHeaders have the same problem

Comment: @Meleak (RE: Row headers), it doesn't appear that way. In my zoomed in image, the row headers are always one unit thick.

Comment: Have you styled the `DataGrid`? I'm pretty sure that when you use the default style, the RowHeaders have 2 separators just like the ColumnHeaders (unless there is some trick that I'm unaware of). Uploaded a screenshot of this here: http://www.mediafire.com/?3sxx6h5nvh9f1bo

Comment: @Meleak, I removed the row headers from my example, but I do see your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Added two solutions, both will produce result like

[image]

### Solution 1

- Set `SeparatorVisibility="Collapsed"` for `DataGridHeaderBorder`
- Add Left and Right Separator as `Border`s
- Handle **Hover**, **Pressed** and **Sorted** in Triggers
- Add a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero

**Xaml**

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
              xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="normalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF2F2F2" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEFEFEF" Offset="0.4" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE7E8EA" Offset="0.4" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDEDFE1" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="pressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF7A9EB1" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF7A9EB1" Offset="0.4" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5091AF" Offset="0.4" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4D8DAD" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="hoveredBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF88CBEB" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF88CBEB" Offset="0.4" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF69BBE3" Offset="0.4" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF69BBE3" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="sortedBrush" Color="#FF96D9F9"/>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="separatorLeft" Grid.Column="0" Width="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Background="{StaticResource normalBrush}">
                                <Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="-1"/>
                                </Border.RenderTransform>
                            </Border>
                            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder x:Name="headerBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}"
                                                                            SeparatorVisibility="Collapsed">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="separatorRight" Grid.Column="1" Width="1" Background="{StaticResource normalBrush}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="separatorRight" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource pressedBrush}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="separatorLeft" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource pressedBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="separatorRight" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource hoveredBrush}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="separatorLeft" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource hoveredBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                                <Setter TargetName="separatorRight" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource sortedBrush}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="separatorLeft" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource sortedBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                                <Setter TargetName="separatorRight" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource sortedBrush}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="separatorLeft" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource sortedBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <!--...-->
</DataGrid>
```

---

### Solution 2

The Separators for `DataGridColumnHeader` is drawn in the `RenderTheme` method in `DataGridHeaderBorder`. This class is pretty much an "all or nothing" deal since changing any property in it will disable the entire style (no border, no sort-arrows etc.). It is also sealed so we can't derive from it. We can however copy the entire class and make the `DataGridColumnHeader`s use that class instead.

The part that draws the separators looks like this

```
private void RenderTheme(DrawingContext dc)
{
    // ...
            if (this.SeparatorVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                // ...
                // Draw Left Separator
                dc.DrawRectangle(separatorBrush, null, new Rect(0, 0.0, 1.0, Max0(renderSize.Height - 0.95)));
                // Draw Right Separator
                dc.DrawRectangle(separatorBrush, null, new Rect(renderSize.Width - 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, Max0(renderSize.Height - 0.95)));
            }
```

From here we could just remove the Left Separator and we would get a Separator Width of 1 instead of 2 but then we would get the wrong coloring for the left side when **Hovering**, **Pressing** or **Sorting** a column. To overcome this we can move the Left Separator by 1 to the Left and change the ZIndex so **Hovering** etc. gets higher ZIndex than normal coloring. For this to work we also need to bind ZIndex of `DataGridColumnHeader` to ZIndex of `DataGridColumnBorder`.

We can use it like this

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid>
                            <local:MyDataGridHeaderBorder Panel.ZIndex="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}, Path=(Panel.ZIndex), Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </local:MyDataGridHeaderBorder>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" Panel.ZIndex="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Panel.ZIndex="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <!--...-->
</DataGrid>
```

**MyDataGridHeaderBorder** was to big to post so I uploaded it here: [MyDataGridHeaderBorder.cs](http://www.mediafire.com/?uum39yrj8311fsw)

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it would be this complicated just to change the thickness of some lines.

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: Well it really shouldn't. The problem is that they're drawn in code behind and, as you can see in my post, the width is static 1.0. If there is an easier way I've never been able to find it :) The solution I've been using is the second one. I came up with the first one now as I was writing the answer so I added them both

Answer (score 20):

To avoid this just add below property setting in DataGridColumnHeader style.

```
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-1,0,0" />
```

The issue in this datagrid is the border drawing is happening inside header cell boundry on left side. This is causing the additional lining as shown in the picture above. If you also set datagrid's broderthickness then issue will appear on for top side of the cell also.

Hope this settings will solve problem when thickness is '1'. For other thicknesses you know now what you have to adjust :)

Answer (score -1):

Just set left border thichkness in HeaderStyle to 0:

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,1,1"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This one modifies the border around the whole header, not the individual header cells.